# Law of motion of accelaration applying average velocity

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Consider the law of motion of acceleration:

$s=1/2at^2$

Develop the law decomposing the acceleration:

$s=1/2 * (V/t) *t^2 = 1/2*(V*t) = V/2  *t$

So we can say that the space is the moltiplication between the average velocity ( maximum velocity of the uniformly accelerated motion / 2 ) and the time used to tread all the route.

With the graphic:

[image]

The horizontal line is the average velocity, the oblique line is the velocity with costant acceleration.
I think that my reasoning works, but the spaces treaded by the two lines are different (I tried with some values). I don't know why that happens because the algebric part is right (I hope). I think that the graphic is right too, because the part of the line over the average velocity is the same of the part which is under the average velocity, so I think that they should annul and the result should be exactly the horizontal line. Why isn't it right? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The distances traveled are the same.

You are expressing the constant acceleration $a$ in terms of the velocity after a certain time has elapsed: $a=v(T)/T=V/T$, and so the velocity $v$ as a function of time $t$, assuming the object starts at rest, is

$$v(t)=\frac VTt$$

And so the distance traveled in a time $T$ is

$$s(T)=\int_0^Tv(t)\,\text dt=\int_0^T\frac VTt\,\text dt=\frac V2T$$

This is equivalent to the distance traveled in the other case you consider, where the object travels at a constant speed of $V/2$ for a time period $T$.